# C# UdpClient ".Receive" only giving part of packet identified by wireshark

Tags: c#, networking, udp, wireshark

Basically my code is only capturing part of the UDP protocol packet when I need it to get all of it.

```
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(43965);
IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 43965);

long count = 0;

while(1 == 1)
{
    if (listener.Available > 0)
    {
        byte[] data = listener.Receive(ref endpoint);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
    }
}
```

I'm getting (highlighted):

[image]

I should be getting:

[image]

Comment: Still not clear what you are getting. Just string "MICS"?

Comment: Are you sure that there aren't any null bytes? (null bytes = bytes with value 0) They will usually function as an "end of string" identifier when the text is rendered. For instance, `MICS\0lm` (where `\0` is a null byte) will be rendered as `MICS`

Comment: Visual Vincent you were right, thanks.

Comment: Now im getting all the values after MICS but why doesn't it get the values before MICS

Comment: I converted the bytearray to a hex string btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Visual Vincent said, "MICS" is followed by 0x10 and then 0x00, so if you treat that part of the packet as a null-terminated string, it's "MICS\x10".

As you've discovered, you have to look at the raw bytes to find the data after it.

The data *before* it is the UDP header, the IP header, and the Ethernet header.  You don't get those headers when reading from a UDP socket, you just get the UDP payload.